# mybinder, Error Starting Kernel, Failed to fetch

Tags: ipython, jupyter, mybinder

How to solve with https://mybinder.org/ error *Error Starting Kernel*, *Failed to fetch*?
It worked in the past.

Path to github
https://github.com/itsergiu/Predict-S-P-500-correction-with-Shiller-PE-Ratio-and-Buffet-Indicator

Path to mybinder
https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/itsergiu/Predict-S-P-500-correction-with-Shiller-PE-Ratio/HEAD

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launches from your repo work just fine at present.
The notebook runs starting running well once the session is spun up. It won't run the code `gdp_data = fred.get_series_latest_release('GDP')` in cell 92.

My guess is you got a rare bad launch or bad kernel. Or you had walked away and the session timed out before you tried it? You need to re-launch if the session times out.

---

By the way, the launch URL on your README would be best as the following so that the single notebook that you have opens right up for users without requiring them to find it in the file listing:

```
https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/itsergiu/Predict-S-P-500-correction-with-Shiller-PE-Ratio-and-Buffet-Indicator/HEAD?labpath=Prediction%20of%20S%26P%20500%20correction%20within%20next%206%20months.ipynb
```

Code for accompanying badge with the direct to notebook launch:

```markdown
https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/itsergiu/Predict-S-P-500-correction-with-Shiller-PE-Ratio-and-Buffet-Indicator/HEAD?labpath=Prediction%20of%20S%26P%20500%20correction%20within%20next%206%20months.ipynb
```